# how to remove space from string containing '<' symbol in php?

Tags: php, string

My string contains '`<`' symbol. 
Example:

```
$str = "S t a c k < o v e r f l o w";
```

when i use str_replace() as

```
$str = str_replace(' ', '', $str);
echo $str;
```

The output is:

```
Stack
```

All the letters after `<` are not printed.
where i am wrong? Please Help!

Comment: What you are seeing is 'Stack' ... and the tool you use to see the output clips the rest (lemme guess : browser ?).  In console, this works as you would expect.

Comment: It work correctly in https://3v4l.org/OGcok . Because string contain `<` browser consider it as tag start. So use `htmlspecialchars()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The characters are not lost, and the str_replace is working fine. The problem is that when you output the resulting string the '<' is mistaken for the start of an  html tag and the rest of the string (after the '<') as the tag itself. The tag part therefore is not visible for display.

You can see this if you change your code to:

```
$str = "S t a c k < o v e r f l o w";
$str = htmlspecialchars(str_replace(' ', '', $str));
echo $str;
```

the output then will display as:

```
Stack<overflow
```

Answer (score 1):

Use htmlspecialchars with it

```
htmlspecialchars(str_replace(' ', '', $str));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this way:

```
$str = "S t a c k < o v e r f l o w";
```

**Replace < with #**

```
$str = str_replace('<', '#', $str);
```

**Replace Space with No Space**

```
$str = str_replace(' ', '', $str);
```

**Replace # with Space**

```
$str = str_replace('#', ' ', $str);

echo $str;
```

**Output**

```
Stack Overflow
```

*Or You can Do this way if there are html atgs in the string*

```
// Variable to check
$str = "<h1>Hello World!</h1>";

// Remove HTML tags from string
$newstr = filter_var($str, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
echo $newstr;
```

Reference: [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_func_sanitize_string)